# ipad record video only in small portion of the screen

Tags: ios, ipad, avfoundation, video-recording

I can record video on full screen of ipad with custom overlays. But the problem is i want to keep recording the video only on one portion of the view of ipad and rest of the ipad view i want other funcitonalities. Any idea if and how can we do that?

Comment: Nope.Up mark the question to get comments . I need this too.

Comment: Did you see my response below?

Answer (score 1):

You should use two classes that apple has written. They are called `AVCamPreviewView` which is a subclass of UIView and `AVCamViewController` that is the view controller that manages the view.

You can download both [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/avcam/introduction/intro.html).

Once you have downloaded and added these to your project implementation is very easy. All you do is add a viewcontroller and select `AVCamViewController` in the classes option. Then, add a `UIView` to your viewcontroller and select `AVCamPreviewView` as the class. Finally, you will see that the viewcontroller has a bunch of `IBOutlets` and `IBActions` that you will may to connect to buttons et voila (the only outlet you must connect is the one to the `AVCamPreviewView`.